# Shared Google Sheets

Tags: authorization, share

I'm creating a sheet for Round Management, which a client should pay for. If I share a sheet with somebody, after they've paid, can they then share it with a third party without my consent?

I've no experience of this; I normally work with Excel, but Excel has no real means of preventing copying so I'm considering 'converting'!